# Discord.js Know how many users are in all the guilds of the bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a discord bot in discord.js v12.
And I want to know how many users are in all of the servers that my bot is in.
And I don't want to count the same user multiple times, that will false the results.
Also I don't want to count the bots.

Here's my code, (that gives me the amount of users and bots, and also give me multiple times one user, because he is in multiple servers that the bot is in):

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === PREFIX + "total members") {
        msg.channel.send(bot.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a + g.memberCount, 0))
    }
})
```

Hope you can help.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to `.filter()` after your reduce. You should probably use a `Set` to de-dupe. Try that and edit your post with information if you get stuck. Otherwise this reads as a "gimme teh codez" question which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: hum, I just don't know out to do it, that's why I ask, and I think that's how Stackoverflow works, so yeah I'm here to ask the solution of my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=users) and filter out the bots.

**You can't fetch all the `User`s, they are cached automatically up to 75k users when an event `GUILD_CREATE` is emitted on the websocket for each guild.** According to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#guild-create). For discord.js v13, you would need to enable the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent.

Note that you can't use [`UserManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) to fetch all the users, because it has a required parameter **id**. (Referring to Thunder's answer.)

```js
// A Discord.Collection of users
const users = client.users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot);
// Use .size property to access the total count of cached users
console.log(users.size);
```

**There is no guarantee, that all the users will be sent over to the client on the `GUILD_CREATE` event, for more accurate solution see the one below.**

You could use [`GuildMemberManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) to fetch all the `GuildMember`s of each guild. See example below (`userIds` **should** be guaranteed to contain all the unique ids of users, even if they are offline):

```js
// Initialize a storage for the user ids
const userIds = new Set();
// Iterate over all guilds (always cached)
for (const guild of client.guilds.cache.values()) {
    // Fetch all guild members and iterate over them
    for (const member of (await guild.members.fetch()).values()) {
        // Fetch the user, if user already cached, returns value from cache
        // Will probably always return from cache
        const user = await client.users.fetch(member.id);
        // Check if user id is not already in set and user is not a bot
        if (!userIds.has(user.id) && !user.bot) {
            // Add unique user id to our set
            userIds.add(user.id);
        }
    }
}
// Use .size property to access the size of the set
console.log(userIds.size);
```

Note that `client` is an instance of [`Discord.Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client).

<sub>Tested using discord.js `^12.5.3`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Skulaurun Mrusal's answer, you want to make sure that all users of the bot are in the cache before counting the size. So to do that, you'd fetch all of the users before getting the size of the cache.

Code below:

```js
// Get all the users and dump to cache before filtering
await client.users.fetch()
const users = client.users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot);
console.log(users.size);
```

(Because in large bots not all users are cached, and without fetching all users might count 25-50% of the true count of users)

Comment: That won't work, you can't fetch all the users using `UserManager`. [`UserManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) has a required parameter **id**.

Comment: That's odd, I have been using `client.users.fetch()` in 4 bots without issue. I have even tested `client.users.fetch()` itself on a test bot, the size of cache always changes after that. Discord.js docs aren't always accurate :)

Comment: Tested using Discord.js v12.5.3

Comment: Throws an error for me on both discord.js v13 and v12.

Comment: That's odd... (at least for v12, who knows what else changed in v13)

Answer (score -1):

There is a fast and proven code that i wrote:

```
var usersCount= 0;
client.guilds.cache.mapValues(guild => {
const _x = client.guilds.cache.get(guild.id);
      usersCount += client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a + g.memberCount, 0)
});
message.channel.send(usersCount);
usersCount = 0;
```

Comment: He asked to not count the same user twice.

Comment: ah srry, you can still make an array of users then use if (user[i] === array[i]) {return;}